# Command line based HTTP POST to retrieve data from javascript-rich webpage

Tags: java, javascript, linux, command-line, http-post

I'm not sure if this is possible but I would like to retrieve some data from a web page that uses Javascript to render data. This would be from a linux shell.

What I am able to do now:

1. http post using curl/lynx/wget to login and get headers from command line
2. use headers to get into 'secure' locations in the webpage on command line

However, the only elements that are rendered on the page are the static html. Most of the info  I need are rendered dynamically with js (albeit eventually as a html as well) and don't show up on a command line browser. I understand the issue is with the lack of a js interpreter.

As such... some workarounds I thought might be possible are:

1. calling full browsers from command line and somehow passing the info back to stdout. this would mean that I have to be able to POST.
2. passing the headers (with session info, etc...)  i got from curl to one of these full browsers and again dumping the output html back to stdout. it could very be a printscreen function on the window if all else fails.
3. a pure java solution would be OK too.

Anyone has any experience doing something similar and succeeding?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where the info comes from? Is it generated with javascript (for example calculation of some values), or is it dynamically loaded via ajax?

Comment: looks to me like the js basically parses some JSON data and formats it nicely on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) to do, just that you need have web browser installed. There are other solution as well such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (without browser but might behave differently).

You can find example of Selenium project at [here](https://github.com/paukiatwee/selenium-boostrap).

**WebDriver**

> WebDriver is a tool for writing automated tests of websites. It aims
>   to mimic the behaviour of a real user, and as such interacts with the
>   HTML of the application.

**Selenium**

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is
>   entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications
>   for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
>   Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be
>   automated as well.

**HtmlUnit**

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.

I would recommend use `WebDriver` because it is not required standalone server like `Selenium`, while for `HtmlUnit` might suitable if you dont want install browser without worry about [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) in headless environment.

Comment: looks interesting. i'm gonna check them out now

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see what [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) can do for you. It has numerous language drivers (Java included) that can be used to interact with the browser to process content typically for testing and verification purposes. I'm not exactly sure how you can get exactly what you are looking for out of it but wanted to make you aware of its existence and potential.

Comment: hi laz, thanks for the recommendation. gotta give the vote to kiat wee as he suggested webdriver first. seems really cool!

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible unless you setup a websocket, and even like this I guess it really depends.
Could you detail your objective? For my personal curiosity :-)

Comment: Haha I'm a micro-management nut job. I'm writing a mobile app for myself to keep track of statistics regarding my app business by the hour. 

There's this analytics solution provider that I'm using which has a great web UI but does not have a friendly mobile site or app for me to retrieve data on the go. 

I'm tired of using opera (somehow the js screws up on dolphin) on my mobile and waiting for the rendering. So I was thinking perhaps I could do a crontab on one of my linux servers and then retrieving the data from my custom app on my phone.

Comment: usually the UI does not create data, why don't you get the data from the same source (therefore the server), it would be easier isn't it?